# Android - Google maps changed my app name to "Active App" after installatin

Tags: android

After implementing the Google maps in my app, my app name is changed to "Active App"(means when i install it in my phone or in genymotion , it's name is Active App instead of the real name) and it's never being changed to another name.

This is my manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="param.app.college_selector"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <permission
        android:name="edu.bloomu.huskies.tsc71523.skatelogger.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="edu.bloomu.huskies.tsc71523.skatelogger.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permisson.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logooo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBJ73Xds5eFulFwjJHphZfBru_bQ_Vb-TQ" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".StartPage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_start_page" >
        </activity><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="param.app.college_selector"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <permission
        android:name="edu.bloomu.huskies.tsc71523.skatelogger.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="edu.bloomu.huskies.tsc71523.skatelogger.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permisson.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logooo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBJ73Xds5eFulFwjJHphZfBru_bQ_Vb-TQ" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".StartPage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_start_page" >
        </activity>
```

In this I have also tried to define the name of the app by myself, but it also does not work.
I have also tried to make other apps using Google Maps, but in them also the app name is changed to "active app".

Comment: why you have 2 application tag?

Comment: What is `@string/app_name`?

Comment: The tutorial means to combine the example with your own manifest. Not to declare an extra one.

Comment: Find in project "@string/app_name" surely this value is repeated and this overriding your original value

Comment: no "@string/app_name" is used only once in the manifest . this thing happens in every app when i use google maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it myself -
I just changed the label of my launcher activity.

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="College Selector" 
>
```